# SlickGrid and jqueryUI buttons

Tags: jquery-ui, slickgrid

I'm trying to use

```
$("button").button();
```

but jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js used by SlickGrid doesn't have the button Widget. Is possible to fix this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you have to do is [download](http://jqueryui.com/download) jquery-ui again. selecting the widget button. then replace the old js with the new one.
that should do the trick.
what happens its that slick grid uses a reduced version of jquery-ui, optimize. but you can use a complete version if you want.